# Hadoop: write once read many

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop programming and in all the articles on Hadoop that i have read, there is a statment which says that hadoop follows write once and read many times paradigm.

What does write once and ready many times mean in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of Hadoop,there no support for an append operation. Once the file is in HDFS then it is immutable. So, you place the file into HDFS once and can read the file 'n' number of times.

HBase supports data appends and it is hadoop's database.

Comment: Append has been disabled because HBase doesn't need it anymore.

Comment: Does that mean that the newer versions support append? Is write once not applicable anymore?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Why is the append not needed anymore? Can you please throw some light?